# How to mention(configure) multiple log folder locations in filebeat?

Tags: elastic-stack

How to mention multiple folder locations in filebeat.yml configuration file.
i mean:

```
- input_type: log

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
   -  D:/LOG1folder/*.log
```

like how can i add another log folder path in the same configuration file.i want to add multiple logfolders.

eg :

```
- input_type: log

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /LOG1folder/*.log, /LOG2folder/*.log,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-configuration.html) suggest as a list

```
- input_type: log

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /LOG1folder/*.log
    - /LOG2folder/*.log
```

Comment: perfect solution. Thanks doctorlove.